# Could not use references in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Have the same constraints with any linked .dll in visual studio project:

Could not add a reference to: "path/to/any/library.dll" one of the following reasons:

- Target a higher version of .net framework
- Not a net assembly
- Not registered ActiveX control

No idea what to do

Comment: Have you checked all of those things that the error mentions?

Comment: First off all I can not check which version of .net framework project used. I don't have any suggestions in configuration properties / general